# How to set the X axis of a scattered chart in VBA excel?

Tags: excel, vba

Here is my problem:

I got this code:

```
'Draw a chart
Dim rng As range
Dim cht As ChartObject

'Your data range for the chart
Set rng = ActiveSheet.range("$G$2:$G$" & row_Position & ",$Z$2:$AC$" & row_Position)

'Create a chart
Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add( _
    Left:=ActiveCell.Left, _
    Width:=775, _
    Top:=275, _
    Height:=250)

cht.Activate

'Populate chart with data
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=rng

'Add gridlines
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).HasMajorGridlines = True

'Determine the chart type
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
```

So, the code gets me a chart that looks like this:

[image: cht1]

So, allow me to explain this line:

```
Set rng = ActiveSheet.range("$G$2:$G$" & row_Position & ",$Z$2:$AC$" & row_Position)
```

G2 to G+row_Position, represents the dates and time of a button click (on button click I add a new row into the table)

Z2 to AC+row_Position, represents the 4 columns I want to have displayed in my chart.

As you can see, in the picture above, it works.

My problem:

I have a new column now, it's F2 to F+row_Position, they are the index of the row, so numbers, from 1 to row_Position.

For the matter of fact, my chart is a scatter chart, and it is not equidistant, for that, I wanted to replace the G (Dates and time) column with the F column...but the following is resulting from that, please have a look:

Code changed to:

```
Set rng = ActiveSheet.range("$F$2:$F$" & row_Position & ",$Z$2:$AC$" & row_Position)
```

And now, it looks like this:

With 2 rows:
[image: cht2]

With 3 rows:
[image: cht3]

And so on, until it comes to 6 rows:

[image: cht4]

So, just the change from G to F caused this error...

I just wanted to replace the dates with row numbers, to generate a scatter chart with equidistant feature turned on, since I could not do it with dates(have no idea how til today)

I hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance.

---

---

---

@edit1: the data is this:

[image]

This is the chart with it:

[image]

This is the chart with the index row:

[image]

So in the end, there are only numbers...nothing special...

Comment: It would probably a good idea to show the data too. Otherwise this cannot be reproduced. See [mcve].

Comment: @PEH please have a look at the edit on the bottom of the question

Comment: Ideal would be a solution where I could keep the dates in the X axis and the chart to be equidistant...

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to keep these dates equidistant don't enter them as date but as text. So eg. if your timestamp is `14.6.2018 9:44:11` type `'14.6.2018 9:44:11` with an apostrophe in the beginning. So Excel recognizes it as text (which makes them equidistant).

Alternatively you can add a helper column to convert the timestamps into text by using a formula. And then using the helper column (text) as x axis.

Formula might be different to your localization but something like …

```
=TEXT(F:F, "DD.MM.YYYY hh:mm:ss")
```